# SanDisk SecureAccess software

Tags: usb, wine

SanDisk USB flash drives come with a password and file encryption software called SecureAccess v1.0 and the update is v2.0. This doesn't work on my UBUntu Studio 12.04 LTS OS. Their website states its only supported in Wndws and Mac. THe error says 'please run SecureAccess from an external Sandisk device'. I'm ok with it not working for now since I haven't stored files in the protected 'Vault' folder yet, however it would be nice to use such. WINE is having problems running this software. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd personally use TrueCrypt or the fork VeraCrypt instead. Wanna bet that there is not either a serious security flaw or an NSA backdoor somewhere in SanDisk SecureAccess?

Answer (score 1):

I know it won't help you with any files you've written from a Mac or Windows computer, but you might consider using the ecryptfs system, in the ecryptfs-utils package.  There is even a PAM module which uses the passphrase you provide to log in to encrypt the passphrase used for encrypting the files and filenames on your USB drive.  Basically, using the standard ecrypt system, you could mount your USB drive at $HOME/.Private and then use the ecryptfs-[u]mount-private utilities to (u)mount your crypted USB drive.

Also of note, yeah....this wouldn't help if you wanted those crypted files to be able to be read on a Mac or Windows 'puter.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go into winecfg using Wine Tricks. Once there, head to the *Drives* tab click "Auto Detect". Once that is done, plug your USB in and see if your USB is detected. If not, manually set the location of your USB.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe SanDisk secure software works with Linux. SanDisk's software is the only way to utilize the built in hardware encryption. So you're stuck with ether using the encryption and only using the drive with Windows or Mac OS machines. Or using an alternative such as VeraCrypt, but without the hardware encryption benefits. Nothing's lost from a security point of view, just encryption speeds may be slower.